# Syntax error when creating view

Tags: mysql, view

I have the following little bit of MySQL code

```
CREATE VIEW UserResults AS 
   SELECT E.No, E. Description
      , Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner)
      , Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner AND Status==’Active’ ) 
   FROM ETable AS E, RTABLE as R
   ORDER BY E.No)
```

but MySQL is returning a syntax error that I can't seem to find. Also when I have created this view, how can I make it viewable?

Comment: What's the syntax error?

Comment: ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 143
STR: ==

Comment: I'm not sure about mySQL but this is not correct right?(Status==’Active’)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have an extra ending parenthesis, which should be removed
- Views should not have `ORDER BY`.
- The `WHERE` clause should not be in the middle of the `SELECT`, you will need to use a `CASE`.
- You are returning a Cartesian product instead of joining your tables together, this may provide more results than you want/expect.

The `R.RID` in the `THEN` block of the `CASE` statements may need to be a `1`, not entirely sure what you hoped to get from those `COUNT` statements you originally had.

I tried to figure out what you were trying to do, and I think this is it:

```
CREATE VIEW UserResults AS
   SELECT E.No, E.Description
      , SUM(CASE 
               WHEN $Username = R.Owner THEN R.RID
               ELSE 0
            END) AS SumOfOwner
      , SUM(CASE
               WHEN $Username = R.Owner AND Status = 'Active' THEN R.RID
               ELSE 0
            END) AS SumOfOwnerAndActive
   FROM ETable AS E
   INNER JOIN RTABLE as R ON E.No = R.ENo
   GROUP BY E.No, E.Description
```

Comment: This was a different result than expected. I probably need to look at how I'm writing my query. Table E only has 10 tuples and at least one tuple from E is completely contained in Table R. I'm trying to create a view that says for the current logged in user how many Rs they have in each E.

Comment: @MadMoney What column links the two tables together?

Comment: They currently exist as 2 separate tables, E.No is the primary key for table E, R.ID is the PK for table R

Comment: @MadMoney Correct, but what column tells you which record(s) of tableE relate to TableR?

Comment: I'm not sure I properly understand the question, but E.No also functions as a FK in Table R. Would it be easier to just condense E.No and E.Description into one column since they're static values?

Comment: @MadMoney The foreign key was what I was looking for.  I've updated my answer to include an INNER JOIN and GROUP BY.  This should be much closer to the data you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Right now I'm getting a "Unknown column 'R.ENo' in 'on clause' "

Comment: @MadMoney You did not provide the structures of your tables, so I could only guess at the names you've given your foreign key columns.  You will have to change those to match your schema.

Comment: I found the column that I needed in all of that. Thank you so much, you are my Oprah.

Answer (score 0):

The Subquery which you create the view from is wrong:

```
SELECT E.No, E. Description, Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner), Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner AND Status==’Active’ ) FROM ETable AS E, RTABLE as R ORDER BY E.No)
```

you can not use where inside a count like:

```
Count(R.RID WHERE $Username= R.Owner)
```

Take a look at the [Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and check the syntax again.

and try to replace the **Status == 'Active'** with **Status = 'Active'**

Once you [created the view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-view.html) you can read it normally like a table usign the **select** keyword

Answer (score 0):

As well as other issues identified in other answers, you need to specify the names of the columns in the view with:

```
CREATE VIEW UserResults(No, Description, UserCount, ActiveCount) AS ...
```

Also, in classic (standard) SQL, you cannot parameterize a view with a variable; the `$Username` notation looks like a parameter - and would not be allowed, therefore.